# Is there a way to display javascript content in blog feeds

Tags: javascript, rss, feed, atom-feed, syndication-feed

Does RSS/Atom have a semi-official method of including active (read:javascript) content in it's items?

I know about RSS enclosures, but I'm presuming that's for true multimedia - ie mp3 and the likes.

Say I have a bit of remote javascript I want to include in my post to display a dynamic graph etc, can this be done?  Or flash, etc for that matter?

And if possible, how many feedreaders would support rendering it?  I guess all the ones with build in browser components would be ok with it, for example Omea Reader.  The web-based ones I'm guessing would have issues though?

Comment: Sounds like allowing what you are asking for is a recipe for XSS...

Comment: over and above anything else on the web today?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge: *No*

- http://cyber.law.harvard.edu/rss/rss.html
- http://atompub.org/rfc4287.html